# Handle Bad Request Errors with NGINX ingress controller

Tags: nginx-ingress

I am using k8s nginx ingress controller https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx and trying to customize error pages in nginx in order to hide server information which is by default sent in error responses by default backend.

It works fine when handling 404s and 503s for example.

For some requests 400 Bad Request can be returned which again exposes server information. If 400 is handled on the custom error backend then underlying servers responses are affected. Is it possible to handle only nginx specific errors and customize only these responses?

Comment: Which error codes do you want nginx to handle, which ones do you want default backend to handle?

Comment: @lukman I want to handle nginx errors with custom error backend, if possible (like 400 bad request which is due to % in the url, or 404 not found when nginx does not have appropriate route mappings...). The idea is not to use default html error pages coming from nginx, but use json responses. All other responses I want to just forward to a client from underlying servers. I don't want to handle 400 from coming from underlying server with this custom backend.